# Substring(string.IndexOf()) está retornando partes indesejadas

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou capturando um [site de músicas](http://static.ritalia.nohup.it/000_new-player.php). Gostaria de retornar somente 2 informações artista e a música. Ela está neste trecho de código:

```
<div class="nowOnAir">
            <a href="http://www.radioitalia.it/artista/edoardo_bennato/1.php" onclick="javascript:loadUrl(this.href);return false;" class="autore" title="Scopri tutto su edoardo bennato">
                edoardo bennato            </a><br />
            <span>le ragazze fanno grandi sogni</span>

        </div>
```

**Artista** = edoardo bennato

**música** = le ragazze fanno grandi sogni

Estou tentando recuperar assim:

```
string musica = resposta.Substring(resposta.IndexOf("<span>"), resposta.IndexOf("</span>"));
string artista = resposta.Substring(resposta.IndexOf("autore"), resposta.IndexOf("</a><br />"));
```

No caso artista ok, sei que tem itens a mais, mas na música pra mim estaria 100% correto, porém ele retorna na música o seguinte conteúdo:

```
"<span>le ragazze fanno grandi sogni</span>\n            \n        </div>\n     \t\n        \n        \n                \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        <div class=\"iTunes\">\n        \n                \n           <a href=\"http://www.amazon.it/gp/redirect.html?camp=2025&creative=165953&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.it%2Fgp%2Fsearch%3Fkeywords%3Dsolo%252Cclaudio%2Bbaglioni%26url%3Dsearch-alias%253Ddigital-music&linkCode=xm2&tag=radiital-21&SubscriptionId=AKIAINZG7TF6TOXSKWSQ\" target=\"_blank\">\n           <img src=\"http://static.ritalia.nohup.it/img/2014/acquista_amazon.jpg\" title=\"Acquista su Amazon\"  alt=\"Acquista su Amazon\" />\n           </a>\n        \n        \n        \n\t\t       <!--http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=24373&a=1945182&url= -->\n        \t<a style=\"background:none;\" href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/it/album/solo/id956867691?i=956867694&uo=4\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://static.ritalia.nohup.it/img/2013/Download_on_iTunes_Badge_IT_110x40_0824.png\" title=\"Scarica su itunes\"  alt=\"scarica\"/></a>\n       \n           \t\t</div>\n\t\t\n\t\t<script>\n        $(document).ready(function(){\n            var mostra=0;\n            $(\".last5\").mousedown(function(){\n                if(mostra==0){\n                    $(\".songs\").fadeIn(\"fast\");\t\n                    mostra=1;\t\n                }else{\n                    $(\".songs\").fadeOut(\"fast\");\t\n                    mostra=0;\t\n                }\n            });\n        \n        \n        });\n\t\t\n        </script>\n       \n        \n        \n        \n     \n    <div class=\"fotoArtista\">    \n       \n    \t<a href=\"http://www.radioitalia.it/multimedia/galleria/artista/1/claudio_baglioni/684.php\" onclick=\"javascript:loadUrl(this.href);return false;\" title=\"Guarda tutte le foto di claudio baglioni\">Foto: 53</a>\n   \n        \n    \t<a href=\"http://www.radioitalia.it/multimedia/video/artista/1/claudio_baglioni/1999.php\"  onclick=\"javascript:loadUrl(this.href);return false;\" title=\"Guarda tutte i video di claudio baglioni\">Video: 35</a>\n\t\n    \t\n    </div>\n        <div class=\"newsArtista\">\n    \t<a href=\"http://www.radioitalia.it/news/1/index.php\"  onclick=\"javascript:loadUrl(this.href);return false;\">\n    \t    Tutte le news\n        </a>\n\t</div>\n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        <div class=\"correlati\">\n            <h3>Artisti consigliati</h3>\n            <ul>\n                                <li><a href=\"http://www.radioitalia.it/artista/emma/1.php\"  onclick=\"javascript:loadUrl(this.href);return false;\" title=\"Emma\"><img src=\"http://static.ritalia.nohup.it/img/icons/artista/55827c6812054.jpg\" border=\"0\" ></a></li>\n                                <li><a href=\"http://www.radioitalia.it/artista/marco_mengoni/1.php\"  onclick=\"javascript:loadUrl(this.href);return false;\" title=\"Marco Mengoni\"><img src=\"http://sta"
```

O que está errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você realmente está pegando as posições erradas.

O início não está considerando os caracteres do que está buscando. Então se está buscando `<span>` você tem que começar 6 caracteres à frente para não pegar a própria *string* de busca.

O segundo parâmetro espera quantos caracteres você quer pegar e não a posição. Então você deve achar a *string* que faz o casamento do final e deve subtrair o que já foi desconsiderado antes, no caso o valor do primeiro parâmetro. Desta forma você tem a quantidade de caracteres e não a posição.

Assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var resposta = @"<div class=""nowOnAir"">
            <a href=""http://www.radioitalia.it/artista/edoardo_bennato/1.php"" onclick=""javascript:loadUrl(this.href);return false;"" class=""autore"" title=""Scopri tutto su edoardo bennato"">
                edoardo bennato            </a><br />
            <span>le ragazze fanno grandi sogni</span>

        </div>";
        var inicio = resposta.IndexOf("<span>") + 6;
        var musica = resposta.Substring(inicio, resposta.IndexOf("</span>") - inicio);
        inicio = resposta.IndexOf("autore") + 6;
        var artista = resposta.Substring(inicio, resposta.IndexOf("</a><br />") - inicio);
        WriteLine(musica);
        WriteLine(artista);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AiAQP6). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/psQLCQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ParseHtml.cs).

Note que o resultado do artista está errado como você reconhece. Adapte ao que precisa agora. Você já sabe onde estava errando.

Um detalhe: ficar *parseando* páginas de terceiros é pedir para ter problemas, a não ser que o criador da página afirme que nunca fará alterações nela. Só faça em desespero.

Comment: Concordo, qualquer mudança no código gerará um erro pra mim, mas como é algo pessoal então se mudar eu mudo tb, tranquilo.